# regex replace Blocks start and end

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying have a source to generate two source, for web and phone, I'd like to write a source js like this:

```
{*Phone
import webfunction from ./utils
*/Phone}
...anothercode..

{*Web
import webfunction from ./utils
*/Web}
...anothercode..
```

I've heard that with regex  is not  easy to replace blocks, inside de blocks will no write  comments or strange chars, but i'dont know what it's the better strings that I can use with regex to get easier this.

If I want to get the pure parte for Phone and save to a new file; i've just call regex function to delete Web part, and vice versa ...

anyone does any idea what is the best string that i can use to achieve this ?

Update 1:
In this case the regex is not working, with two blocks inside `ddd`

```
{*Web
dddd
}
ddd
{*Web
*}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use a configuration file, create a setting named `Target` and switch it from `Phone` to `Web` and vice-versa?

Comment: Maybe. So you want to remove what's inside the `{*Phone[...]*/Phone}` (or Web) block ?

Comment: yes, i will use two regex one to remove Phone or another Web , but i'm not sure if {* *} it's the best  for regex I can use always this chars in a new line

Comment: This is not the same block format that in your original post... What's *all* the formats you want to use?

Comment: I'm just trying to write blocks for phone and webs on my react web project and react native, so i can use one source for both projects, there are minimal differences between a react native project  and react web project, so i need to use blocks to parse and generate js for every project

Comment: Let's continue [in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171853/regex-replace-blocks-start-and-end)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
\{\*(\w+)[\s\S]*?\*\/\1\}
```

And test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/BOd0o4/1/)

Comment: On dirait plutôt *even if I [...]* ;) By the way, the link I provided include an explanation of the regex. If you want more explanations, feel free to ask!

Comment: i've update my answer, it's not working with there is a two blocks... maybe is not better use somethink like:  Carriage Return Phone and Carriage Return EndPhone ?

Comment: @DDave Ok, edit your answer to format the code, and I'll take a look.